# How to map a union in a JNA Structure

Tags: java, jna, unions

I need to convert a couple C structures to java using JNA. My structures are so composed:

```
struct s_xl_event {
XLeventTag tag;
unsigned char chanIndex;
unsigned short transId;
unsigned short portHandle;
unsigned char flags;
unsigned char reserved;
XLuint64 timeStamp;
union s_xl_tag_data tagData;
};

union s_xl_tag_data {
struct s_xl_can_msg msg;
struct s_xl_chip_state chipState;
union s_xl_lin_msg_api linMsgApi;
struct s_xl_sync_pulse syncPulse;
struct s_xl_daio_data daioData;
struct s_xl_transceiver transceiver;
};

struct s_xl_can_msg {
unsigned long id;
unsigned short flags;
unsigned short dlc;
XLuint64 res1;
unsigned char data[MAX_MSG_LEN];
XLuint64 res2;
};
```

I added only the main structures that I needed but also because all the related structure are similar to `s_xl_can_msg`.

In Java I did this using JNA:

```
public static class s_xl_event extends Structure {
    public byte tag;
    public byte chanIndex;
    public short transId;
    public short portHandle;
    public byte flags;
    public byte reserved;
    public long timeStamp;
    public s_xl_tag_data tagData;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("tag","chanIndex","transId","portHandle","flags","reserved","timeStamp","tagData");
    }
}

public static class s_xl_tag_data extends Union {
    public s_xl_can_msg msg;
    public s_xl_chip_state chipState;
    public s_xl_lin_msg_api linMsgApi;
    public s_xl_sync_pulse syncPulse;
    public s_xl_daio_data daioData;
    public s_xl_transceiver transceiver;
}

public static class s_xl_lin_msg extends Structure {        
    public byte id;
    public byte dlc;
    public short flags;
    public byte[] data = new byte[8];
    public byte crc;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("id","dlc","flags","data","crc");
    }
}
```

When I use the method

```
short xlReceive(long portHandle, IntByReference eventCount, s_xl_event eventList);
```

I obtain the values related to all the fields in `s_xl_event` except for `tagData` where all the fields are filled with 0. Now, I'm not sure that I mapped all the sub structures and unions as expected or I forgot something. Has anyone had anything to do with such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a `Union` like `s_xl_tag_data`, you must tell the Union which of its fields is being read by using `setType()` with either the class or field name, and then call `read()` on the Union.

One way of doing this automatically when the parent structure is first populated is by overriding the `read()` method in the parent structure.

Add this method to your `s_xl_event` Structure:

```
public void read() {
    // read from native memory, populate tag
    super.read(); 
    // set union type based on tag
    switch(tag) {
    case XL_RECEIVE_MSG:
    case XL_TRANSMIT_MSG: 
        tagData.setType(s_xl_can_msg.class);
        break;
    case XL_CHIP_STATE: 
        tagData.setType(s_xl_chip_state.class);
        break;
    case XL_LIN_MSG: 
        tagData.setType(s_xl_lin_msg_api.class);
        break;
    // ... add other cases here...
    default:
        // add default type or throw exception etc.  
        break;
    }
    // now read tagData from native memory
    tagData.read();
}
```

As an alternative to passing the class to `setType()` for the union element, you could instead pass a `String` containing the variable name, e.g., `"msg"`, `"chipState"`, or `"linMsgApi"`, etc.

Also of note, the `getFieldOrder()` methods you are using in your `Structure`s are deprecated in the latest version of JNA.  You should use the `@FieldOrder` annotation instead.

Comment: Thank you, it is reading the values on the correct structure! Now I have another issue... the s_xl_can_msg values are in Little Endian order but java is loading as Big Endian... is there a solution to read in the correct order?

Comment: Problem solved, I used a wrong type for a field and so I had more bytes than requested. Now it is working all perfectly!